# I want to make a nested if in Crystal reports

Tags: function, crystal-reports

Please do a final review of your question and then post. I am making a report in crystal reports in product version 11, I want to do an if to know where some cancellations come from since I manage two tables called Data and History, after a certain time the cancellations go to the History table, in the report I created a formula called "Test" that when dragging that field when the cancellation appears I get a D if it comes from the data table or an H if it is from the history table, it is worth mentioning that I do not know much of the syntax of crystal reports, I have been investigating but I can not find a solution. This is the code I am using but I get an error in the last two End If mentioning that the text does not seem to be part of the formula.

```
`If ({SP_CANCELACIONES;1.STATUSDA} = "C") Then
    If (InStr({SP_REPORTE;1.NUMRESDA}, "H_") > 0) Then
        "Historial"
    Else 
        "Datos"
    End If
End If`
```

I tried with this code but I get error in the last two End If sending the message "This part of the text seems not to belong to the formula", I tried putting ; and the brackets but it doesn't work and I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is no End IF in Crystal syntax.  Instead, use something like:

```
If {SP_CANCELACIONES;1.STATUSDA = "C" Then
    If InStr({SP_REPORTE;1.NUMRESDA}, "H_") > 0 Then "Historial" Else "Datos"
ELSE "Not C" ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, as I was reading that's why I used the "()" and the ";".